# Why does zoom does not work in Android Coordinator Layout?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I'm hoping to add persisent bottom dialogs to my Android map app, and have started to modify my activity.xml layout file. However, I have found out that pinch to zoom in/out and the zoom +/- controls do not work. The only thing that does work is the circular "relocate to current location" button (the one thats normally in the top right hand corner of the screen.

My original xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1"
android:id="@+id/tlll"
>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llhelpgraphic"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".08"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/helpButton"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/help5"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/titleview"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/title"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frlayout"
    android:layout_weight=".82"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    >

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".FindIt" />

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".10"
    android:background="#004D79"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/addressText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="Enter UK address or postcode">
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/findButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Find">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

My modified file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/bgLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1"
android:id="@+id/tlll"
>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llhelpgraphic"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".08"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/helpButton"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/help5"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/titleview"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/title"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frlayout"
    android:layout_weight=".82"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    >

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".FindIt" />

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".10"
    android:background="#004D79"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/addressText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="Enter UK address or postcode">
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/findButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Find">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/loclistdialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
  app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/loclist"
            />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The only changes I've made are the addition of the CoordinatorLayout and the NestedScrollView to the file. Can anyone help please?

Comment: As an aside (which I don't seem to have mentioned above), I can drag the map but the zoom functions are not working. I've been doing some investigation into CoordinatorLayout's onInterceptTouchEvent() and OnTouchEvent() methods but I don't see why they should only veto some of the functionality.